# Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController> on <MFSideMenuContainerViewController> whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to load picture chooser in iOS it works fine in the first attempt but when i do this for the second time it gives me the following warning

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

my code for picking image is as follow

```
[self startCameraControllerFromViewController:self usingDelegate:self sourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
```

and the method is as follows startCameraControllerFromViewController

```
- (BOOL) startCameraControllerFromViewController: (UIView*) controller usingDelegate: (id) delegate sourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType) sourceType{

if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
      sourceType] == NO)
    || (delegate == nil)
    || (controller == nil))
{
    DLog(@"no is being returned");
    return NO;


}

if(_delegate != nil &&[ _delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(imagePickerOpened)]){

    [_delegate imagePickerOpened];
}

if(cameraUI==nil){

    //        [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading"];
    [ALERT showLoader];

    dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue=dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
        cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        cameraUI.sourceType = sourceType;

        cameraUI.mediaTypes=cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];
        cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;

        cameraUI.delegate = delegate;


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:cameraUI animated:YES];
            //[self presentModalViewController:cameraUI animated:YES ];

            [ALERT hideLoader];
        });


    });
}
else{
    cameraUI.sourceType = sourceType;
    [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:cameraUI animated:YES];
    //[self presentModalViewController:cameraUI animated:YES ];
}

return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was related setting root view controller i had set a root view controller that was not present so i set my current view controller to be root view controller and it fixed my issue.

Comment: I don't get it how did you fix this issue? I am running into problem with similar code

Comment: my code was quite big so cannot post my whole code.just see that what is your root view controller and is that the same root view controller  which present i am sure they will be different.